# Preserving duplicate index of a pandas df when converting to python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing, duplicates

I have a df which have a dublicate index at `'2020-10-25 02:00:00'` with different values:

```
df
...                    5
2020-10-25 02:00:00    10
2020-10-25 02:00:00    7
...                    8
```

because of the summer/winter time change I have this duplicate index. It is fine till I want to change this df to dictionary via `df.to_dict()`. When I change it to dictionary one of the values of `df['2020-10-25 02:00:00']` is removed, since dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Instead of hardcoding, I am looking for something like following, which could maybe store these two values as a list when converting into a dictionary:

```
df.to_dict(preserve_duplicates=True)
```

**Summary: Is there a way to preserve duplicate index of a df, when it is converted to python dictionary?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to group those values together (i.e. to a list) before you convert the df to dict:

```
                     value
date
2020-10-25 01:00:00      5
2020-10-25 02:00:00     10
2020-10-25 02:00:00      7


df.groupby(df.index).agg(list).to_dict()
> {'value': {'2020-10-25 01:00:00': [5], '2020-10-25 02:00:00': [10, 7]}}
```

The `agg` function can be flexible depending on your need, you can also do a sum or any other operations.

Comment: is it also possible to create df from this dictionary? and coming back to the same df that you typed first?

Comment: @oakca Yes, you can simply do `pd.DataFrame(...).explode("value")`.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate index in a Pandas dataframe should be avoided, but in a Python dict, they are just impossible.

IMHO, the simplest way is just to reset the index before building the dict:

```
df.reset_index().to_dict()
```